# Conflict between Spring data MongoDb and Elasticsearch

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb, spring-data-elasticsearch

I started a project in which I use both Mongo, Elasticsearch and spring boot.

With either technologies by itself, the project works just fine.  However with both together, they conflict.  I saw this particular article that seemed to be similar to my issue.
https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAES-57
So I tried it out and it the problem is still there.

I put these on the Main class

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = MongoRepositoriesAutoConfiguration.class)
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = "com.searchizi.mongo.repository")
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories(basePackages = "com.searchizi.elasticsearch.repository")
@ComponentScan
public class Application implements CommandLineRunner { … }
```

A shortened form the the exception trace is this

The class `SearchiziUser` is in the `com.searchizi.mongo.model` package. It is not on the Elasticsearch scan path.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to identify index name. SearchiziUser is not a Document. Make sure the document class is annotated with @Document(indexName="foo")
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.isTrue(Assert.java:65)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchTemplate.getPersistentEntityFor(ElasticsearchTemplate.java:869)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchTemplate.createIndexIfNotCreated(ElasticsearchTemplate.java:684)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchTemplate.createIndex(ElasticsearchTemplate.java:135)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.AbstractElasticsearchRepository.createIndex(AbstractElasticsearchRepository.java:80)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.AbstractElasticsearchRepository.<init>(AbstractElasticsearchRepository.java:72)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.SimpleElasticsearchRepository.<init>(SimpleElasticsearchRepository.java:36)
```

The scanning for each repository type should be separated but apparently it is not.  Any idea what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is clearly a bug in Spring Data Elasticsearch as it seems to scan for domain types in packages it actually shouldn't. I filed [DATAES-??](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAES-136) for you. Also, I filed a ticket so that Spring Data Elasticsearch supports the new multi-store configuration improvements so that you shouldn't have to explicitly configure separate packages.

On a side note, excluding the auto-configuration is not necessary if you set up `@EnableMongoRepositories` as it will automatically disable Spring Boot's auto-configuration.

Comment: thanks I will create an example project and attach a link to it in https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAES-136

Answer (score 0):

I faced this exception and I resolved by change version of elasticsearch and mongodb lib versions

```
<!-- Spring data mongodb -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- mongodb java driver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- ELASTICSEARCH -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```